# C# Webform ClientID prefix is a integer

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms

I'm combining `ASP.NET MVC`and `WebForm`. When I do a `Html.RenderPartial("xx")` where xx contains a `Webform` the `ClientID` of this one is an integer. I doesn't seem to find the parent page through a `RenderPartial`! Anyone is aware of this behaviour? Could I possibly put a prefix? I'm using .NET 3.5 so I can set the `ClientID` to be `static` and I don't want to move to .NET 4. Is as the WebForm rendered by `RenderPartial` didn't see this parent Page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you give us some sample code to demonstrate your scenario?  We can then provide a solution that matches your example